# How to hide a shipping method in front end and visible on admin section Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, shipping, frontend

How can I enable shipping method only in admin section and hide from frontend in magento 2?

Comment: "How can I enable shipping method only in admin section and hide from backend in magento 2? " any typo here?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out, I've just corrected. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case, your override **your shipping method Model class** and collectRates() function  return false .

Suppose, you want to disabled flat rate for frontend.

In this case,you need override the `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate`.

### di.xml (Namespace\Modulename\etc)

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>    
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
> <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Carrier\Flatrate" />
> </config>
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly well, actually, I didn't need to override from di.xml because I already had my custom model. so I tested if the area code is adminhtml or storefront and switched accordingly.

Comment: @Amit I know this is not related to question, but I'm facing issues at backend in rendering the shipping methods. While creating order from backend, it doesn't show shipping methods however at frontend it shows flat rate and table rates. Do you know the reason?