# How to disable shipping method if weight is more than 30 Kg

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, rules, product-weight

I installed this extension

> ***https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-table-rate-shipping-extension.html***

to manage shipping rates

but i want to hide it or disable it if  weight is more than 30 kg any help please

Comment: get your weight and check.I think so.

Comment: i know how to chech ut where to check to disable this method

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252398/magento-2-hide-shipping-method-in-frontend I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Shipping set

> weight_from 0 and weight_to 30