# Magento 2.3.5: How to hide Shipping Method

Tags: module, orders, shipping-methods, plugin, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to do this thing if customer orders over `$50` then give free shipping method will be shown and if customer orders below `$15` flat order will be shown and free shipping will be hide.

Comment: have you checked this answer **https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252422/73212**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How To Setup `Flat Rate` Shipping:**

( More Details - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-flat-rate.html )

*Navigation:* Login to Magento Backend > Stores > Settings : Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Flat Rate

```
* Enabled: Yes
* Title: Flatrate Shipping
* Method Name: Flatrate Shipping
* Type: Per Order
* Price: <ENTER_DESIRED_PRICE>
* Calculate Handling Fee: Fixed
* Handling Fee: 0.00
* Show Method if Not Applicable: No
* Sort Order: 10
```

**How To Setup `Free` Shipping:**

( More Details - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-free.html )

**Navigation:** Login to Magento Backend > Stores > Settings : Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Free Shipping

```
* Enabled: Yes
* Title: FREE Economy Shipping
* Method Name: FREE Economy Shipping
* Minimum Order Amount: 50.00
* Show Method if Not Applicable: No
* Sort Order: 20
```

.

.

That being said - IFF you need the ability to Show/Hide Shipping Methods based on more Complex/Customizable Business-Rules per se - I'd highly recommend you check out [MageWorx Shipping Suite Extension](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html) module.